# StackExchange.Redis: No connection is available to service this operation: SET

Tags: c#, .net, stackexchange.redis

I created a Console Application running on .NET Core 1.1 and I'm referencing the StackExchange.Redis NuGet package, version 1.2.3

When running the code below, I get the following error:

*It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING*

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;

namespace RedisConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet(BitConverter.GetBytes(5), "asdf");
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the Connect string to `"localhost,abortConnect=false"`, then I get this error message:

*No connection is available to service this operation: SET \u0005\0\0\0; SocketFailure on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 1s ago, last-write: 1s ago, unanswered-write: 27780s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 20s ago*

I followed the [Basics guide](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics) to get started using this library but I keep getting the errors above.

Am I missing some code or configuration?

Comment: The error in both cases means that the client cannot connect to your redis server. On which port is your redis server running on your local host? Do you have configured a password? Can you connect with redis-cli?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have only set up the StackExchange.Redis client, did you install and start up your local Redis server? If not, use HomeBrew to download and install Redis on your machine

```
brew install redis
brew services start redis
```

and start the server with

```
redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ssl=True,abortConnect=False,sslprotocols=tls12` under your connection string